# Show WiFi List and Connect WiFi from command line interface in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, wireless, password, wpa-supplicant, wifi-direct

I use ubuntu 16.04. I have design one webpage,in webpage They show wifi list Then I select one wifi network and enter password of this network.

So I will make 2 scripts,they running in background on my system.

in first script they show wifilist of my system in json form.

In second script, I store ssid and password in json file and then i write on my wifi-config file.

Please guide me to making two scripts, what command I use to connect my wifi and where I store my wifi password?

Comment: do you already know the ssid and pw?

Comment: yes, user can select network then enter password of network.but after where am I store password in system?to connect wifi successfully.

Comment: do you know both ssid and pw? you dont need to store the password.. if you know the ssid and pw.. you can connect to this network by a single command and the password is automatically stored if it is correct..

Comment: `nmcli device wifi list` it lists the availabel networks.. since you already know the ssid.. you can directly enter `nmcli device wifi connect $ssid` it will prompt you to enter pw. since you already know the pw.. you can run this command `nmcli device wifi connect $ssid password $yourpassword`

Comment: thank you for reply. once i will try update you soon.

Comment: at the first time, i have connected to my ethernet. then i run this command:`nmcli device wifi connect $ssid`                                                                                         it gives Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: Active connection removed before it was initialized

Comment: run this command `sudo nmcli device wifi connect $ssid`
Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: Active connection removed before it was initialized

Comment: Hi, what is the ssid? if your ssid is `ABCDEFGH` the command should be `nmcli device wifi connect ABCDEFGH` no need of `sudo`

Comment: `nmcli device wifi connect aditya`
Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: Not authorized to control networking.

Comment: with sudo try once? are you not the admin user?

Comment: sudo nmcli device wifi connect aditya
Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: Active connection removed before it was initialized

Comment: I am admin of my ubuntu pc.

Comment: can you try to add the wifi network via GUI and see if the error occurs?

Comment: no, in GUI they connect directly wtihout error.